# Why do I get "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"?

Tags: python, pygame

When I use in the program `querauto_group.add(QuerWagen.create_querauto())` then I get the report
`missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. When I use `querauto_group.add(player.create_querauto())` then the program works.

```py
import pygame, sys
import random

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    

    def create_querauto(self):  
        ii=random.randrange(0,8)
        img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/geg{ii}.png") 
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(100,25)) 
        return QuerWagen(200,300,img)
       
class QuerWagen(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_x,pos_y,img):
        super().__init__()
        self.image=img      
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (pos_x,pos_y))
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x+=5  
        if self.rect.x > screen_width + 200:
            self.kill()
    def create_querauto(self): 
        ii=random.randrange(0,8)
        img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/geg{ii}.png") 
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(100,25)) 
        return QuerWagen(200,300,img)        
 
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen_width,screen_hight = (1200,800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_hight))

player = Player()
querauto_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

WECHSELBILD = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(WECHSELBILD,1800)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type ==WECHSELBILD:               
                #querauto_group.add(QuerWagen.create_querauto())
                querauto_group.add(player.create_querauto())
          
    screen.fill((30,30,30))   
    querauto_group.draw(screen)   
    querauto_group.update()   
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On both classes create_querauto is an instance method, meaning that the class needs to be instantiated in order to call the method.

That's why it is working with the player instance.
i.e.

```py
class Player:
    def create_querauto(self):  
        ii=random.randrange(0,8)
        img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/geg{ii}.png") 
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(100,25)) 
        return QuerWagen(200,300,img)

player_instance = Player()
player_instance.create_querauto()  # This will work
Player.create_querauto()           # This will throw the error you see above
```

If you would like to method to work without instantiating the class first you can define it as a static method, using the @staticmethod decorator

This would look like:

```py
class QuerWagen(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    @staticmethod
    def create_querauto(): 
        ii=random.randrange(0,8)
        img = pygame.image.load(f"Bilder/Gegenstaende/geg{ii}.png") 
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(100,25)) 
        return QuerWagen(200,300,img)
```

Now you can call that function on the class directly like you were trying to do.

```py
querwagen = QuerWagen.create_querauto() # works fine
```